# setText dont work with appiun v 1.5.2

Tags: php, android, unit-testing, automated-tests, appium

I am writing a test for my android app, I have a text field where I have to put an input in it, to do this I made this code :

```
 $els = $this->element($this->using('class name')->value('android.widget.EditText'));
        $els->click();
        $els->setText("govin");
```

However when I run this test I have this error :

```
 Something unexpected happened: 'Parameters were incorrect. We wanted {"required":["value"]} and you sent ["elementId","value"]
```

I found that "setText" does not work in appium v1.5.2

Does anybody have an alternative to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in appium v1.5.2,"setText" is not supported, instead you can use "value" function

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this would work on php, I just started learning appium on java windows but you may try `sendKeys("string");`

or try viewing this
https://gist.github.com/aczietlow/7c4834f79a7afd920d8f